# Unable to exit the function after 'window.alert' in Angular9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await, alert

I am trying to calculate time difference and if time difference is greater than 20 mins, I want to display an `alert message` and then exit.
I don't intend to loop through all the `rows` and want to exit the function after finding out the first host which has `minutes < 20`.

```
    this.dataSource.filteredData.forEach(
        async row => {
            this.selection.select(row);
            // const host = row.hostName.substring(0, row.hostName.indexOf('.'));
            const host = 'abc';
            const prevData = await this.myService.getData(host);
            const timeDiff = Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - new Date(prevData[0].dateAt).getTime());
            const minutes = Math.floor((timeDiff / 1000) / 60);
            if (minutes < 20) {
                window.alert('Please check after ' + (20 - minutes) + ' minutes.');
                return false;
            }
        });
```

I am trying to exit the function using `return false` but it is still looping through all the rows.

Updated code without `foreach`:

```
    const f = (async row => {
        const host = 'abc';
        const prevData = this.myService.getData(host);
            const timeDiff = Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - new Date(prevData[0].dateAt).getTime());
            const minutes = Math.floor((timeDiff / 1000) / 60);
        return minutes;
    });

    (async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.dataSource.filteredData.length; i++) {
            const mins = await f(this.dataSource.filteredData[i]);
            if (mins < 200) {
                window.alert('Please retry after ' + (200 - mins) + ' minutes.');
                break;
            }
        }
    })();
```

In the above code, `this.myService.getData(host)` is returning `null`

Comment: There are two issues. The first is you are using forEach, so you will execute the anonymous function for every element. You are also using async, so control will never yield. You need to manually iterate over each row from your own loop, and you need to await the return of your function and capture the result.

Comment: Can you please provide some help on how to iterate and then await the return of function? if you and provide an updated answer that would be really helpful

Comment: sure, I will try to provide in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimally-viable representation of how the control should be programmed:

```
let rows = [1, 2, 3];

let f = (async row => {
  return row === "2";
});

(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    let result = await f(rows[i]);
    console.log(result);
    if (!result)  {
      break;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: I have updated my question and tried to use the answer given by you. In the above code, `this.myService.getData(host)` is returning null

Comment: I am not sure, perhaps the "this" reference is not being scoped correctly (but I thought ES8 would promote the context into fat-arrow function blocks internally. Try capturing a "this" reference before declaring function f:

    `let _this = this;`

    `const f = (async row => {
        const host = 'abc';
        const prevData = _this.myService.getData(host);
            const timeDiff = Math.abs(new Date().getTime() - new Date(prevData[0].dateAt).getTime());
            const minutes = Math.floor((timeDiff / 1000) / 60);
        return minutes;
    });`